# mind mapping based on file system

Tags: file, project-management, directory, mindmapping

I've just started using some mind mapping software (Freemind and Xind) as a replacement for text documents I was previously using to keep track of my work. The main issue (in both cases) is to maintain references to files and folders when I add,remove, or rename them (as every time I have to update the mind map).

What I am looking for is a mind mapping tool that would allow me to:
-automatically generate a folder/file structure in the mind map matching a folder on my filesystem.
-create relations between, add notes to, and change the style of these folders and files.
-whenever a folder/file is added, removed, or renamed, the mind map would automatically be updated accordingly (I'm guessing on linux it would work based on inodes).

Thanks.

Comment: +1 It seems there is no such solution, but it's a very necessary thing for organizing files and ideas in one place simultaneously. Also it's very important to translate actions in the mind map editor into FS (creating, deleting folders).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's looking for a recommendation, and because it has nothing whatsoever to do with programming.

Answer (score 4):

Freemind can create your entire file structure by going to import->folders.

It works fine in freemind or freeplane but is you publish it to the web with the addon, it crashes.  Working on that problem.

Mindjet 8 has a limited capacity but only maps two levels down.  Not very useful.

randy

Answer (score 1):

There is an add-on for [Freeplane](http://www.freeplane.org/) that looks promising for what you are trying to achieve: [dView(indexfile)](https://docs.freeplane.org/getting-started/Add-ons_(install).html#dviewindexfile)

Answer (score 1):

Docear has a mindmap mode which will import a directory structure, create a mind map, allow you to create graphical links between folders, and add notes.  It has a feature "Add Monitoring Folder" and "Re-read Monitoring Folder", but the monitoring feature seems to only work for pdf files and sub-folders with pdf files in them.  It might be a good place to start since it's open source.  (It's based on freeplane).

Answer (score -1):

A sub-optimal solution is to use your file manager as the mind-mapping tool and then using directory names for topics, text files for details/notes and links for inter-relations.

To the best of my knowledge FreeMind and Xmind provide some sort of linking to external files but are not as extensive as what you request.